# stop playing sound when another sound is playing in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, onclicklistener

hello I use MediaPlayer for play sound in my project in android studio
when I click in a button and play sound , and when I click in another button that button play another sound , I want the first sound or another sound be stoped and just the last button that I clicked be played 
I try this code but it not worked

```
package azad.broooska.fartfuns;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MusicFartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private CardView cardView1, cardView2, cardView3, cardView4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_fart);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        cardView1 = findViewById(R.id.card_music1);
        cardView2 = findViewById(R.id.card_music2);
        cardView3 = findViewById(R.id.card_music3);
        cardView4 = findViewById(R.id.card_music4);
        cardView1.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView2.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView3.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        final MediaPlayer s1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bohemian_fartsody);
        final MediaPlayer s2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fart_ballade);
        final MediaPlayer s3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fart_uverture);
        final MediaPlayer s4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.farting_xmas);
        if (id == R.id.card_music1) {
            s1.start();
            s2.stop();
            s3.stop();
            s4.stop();
        } else if (id == R.id.card_music2) {
            s2.start();
            s1.stop();
            s3.stop();
            s4.stop();
        } else if (id == R.id.card_music3) {
            s3.start();
            s2.stop();
            s1.stop();
            s4.stop();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "noThing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating new instances of MediaPlayer each time something is clicked and assigning the variables to new objects; make s1,s2... class property;

```
MediaPlayer s1 ,s2,s3,s4;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_fart);
    //some code
    s1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bohemian_fartsody);
    //assign the rest;
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    if (id == R.id.card_music1) {
        s1.start();
        s2.stop();
        s3.stop();
        s4.stop();
    }
    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: i edited my codes , I have used  implements View.OnClickListener . the problem is not belong to  implements View.OnClickListener

Comment: @Azad Qaderzadeh that's irrelevant; the reason why you can't stop the media is probably because you're calling stop() on an instance other than the one playing. just apply this code and say what happens;

Answer (score -1):

Well, its seems like you don`t want to play very long sounds because you have names like
"fart_ballade" and "fart_uverture" in your code.

If your sounds are not very long it is better to work with the `SoundPool` class.

The `MediaPlayer` class sometimes can cause problems if you switch fast between sounds.

So if your sounds are not that long, you can try the `SoundPool` class.

Here you can learn more about the `SoundPool` class:

[How to use SoundPool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIWPSni7kUk)

I won`t write any code because SoundPool needs more than 5-6 lines of code to work properly.